# Should we add the tag "intention" or "niyyah"?

Tags: discussion, tag

There are a lot of questions regarding intention in this website. Can someone add the tag "intention" or "niyyah"?

I think these questions might be appropriate for the tag "intention":

- [Am I allowed e.g. to change my intention to pray asr after making an initial intention of praying maghrib during the salah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28513/am-i-allowed-e-g-to-change-my-intention-to-pray-asr-after-making-an-initial-int)
- [Is my intention pure](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67685/is-my-intention-pure)
- [question about intention to fast](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67743/question-about-intention-to-fast)
- [Question regarding intention](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/65260/question-regarding-intention)
- [Oaths and intention](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/74145/oaths-and-intention)
- [Is this intention permissible?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/65772/is-this-intention-permissible)

[Just searching for "intention"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=intention) on this website gives 1000+ results.

Comment: Are there? A list of links to questions where you think the tag might be appropriate would be helpful here.

Comment: @goldPseudo Ok, please see the question now.

Comment: [Any user above 150 reputation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) can create a tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made the [niyyah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/niyyah) tag.